# DotNetBrowser inside a ScrollViewer cannot scroll in WPF application

Tags: wpf, dotnetbrowser

I have a WPF application where I put on several DotNetBrowser.WPF.WPFBrowserView elements inside a ScrollViewer vertically.

My problem is that these are not scrolling when I start scrolling with the ScrollViewer. I know that this is just an embedded separated window (or something like that) but I have to made this able to scroll.

Is there any way to achive this?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

1. You can solve this by handling ScrollChanged event for the ScrollViewer.

Here's quick example:

```
 scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += delegate (object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
 {
      browserView.Browser.SetBounds(-(int)e.HorizontalOffset, -(int)e.VerticalOffset, (int)browserView.ActualWidth, (int)browserView.ActualHeight);
 };
```

2. You can also try to use lightwight mode.

   ```
       Browser browser = BrowserFactory.Create(BrowserType.LIGHTWEIGHT);
       var browserView = new WPFBrowserView(browser);
   ```